# Adding a UIVisualEffectView to button

Tags: swift, uibutton, autolayout, uivisualeffectview

i have a transparent delete `UIButton` added to a story board scene, which has a picture as a background, and i have added some auto layout constraints to it.

i want the button background to be a `UIVisualEffectView` so i was thinking of programatically adding the view to where the button is, then removing the button and adding it back so it's on top of the `UIVisualEffectView`.
**Question 1) is this a good idea - or should i find the position in the view hierarchy and place it one level before the button?**

here's what i have thus far. for the `UIButton`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var delete: UIButton! {
    didSet {
        let borderAlpha = CGFloat(0.7)
        let cornerRadius = CGFloat(5.0)
        delete.setTitle("Delete", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        delete.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        delete.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        delete.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: borderAlpha).CGColor
        delete.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
}
```

and for the `UIVisualEffectView`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))
    visualEffectView.frame = delete.frame
    visualEffectView.bounds = delete.bounds
    view.addSubview(visualEffectView)
}
```

this produces a blurred view, the same size as the button, but it's not on top of the button. **Question 2) do i need to somehow pass the auto layout constraints, too?**

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example that you could use in order to insert UIVisualEffectView with vibrancy effect.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 100))
button.setTitle("Visual Effect", forState: .Normal)

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blueColor().CGColor, UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.brownColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor, UIColor.magentaColor().CGColor, UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor, UIColor.cyanColor().CGColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1]
button.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
gradientLayer.frame = button.bounds

let containerEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)
let containerView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: containerEffect)
containerView.frame = button.bounds

containerView.userInteractionEnabled = false // Edit: so that subview simply passes the event through to the button

button.insertSubview(containerView, belowSubview: button.titleLabel!)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(30)

let vibrancy = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: containerEffect)
let vibrancyView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancy)
vibrancyView.frame = containerView.bounds
containerView.contentView.addSubview(vibrancyView)

vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(button.titleLabel!)
```

And, here is what I have done,

- Create a button.
- Create a gradient layer and add it to 0 index of the button.
- Create a container view with effect of UIBlurEffectDark.
- Add the container view to the button.
- Create a vibrancy view with the same effect and add it to the contentView of the above containerView.
- Move the label from button to the vibrancy view's title

And, here is the final result. The titleLabel text blends nicely with vibrancy and the effect applied.

[image]

Comment: if i stop before the bullet point "Add the container view to the button" and replace `button.insertSubview(containerView, belowSubview: button.titleLabel!)` with `button.insertSubview(containerView, belowSubview: button)` the button is no longer responsive (i.e. can't press it). why is this?

Comment: You are adding a new view to button below it's subview button which is not valid, you have to add it to button and below or above certain subviews of the button itself.

Comment: thanks for your response. i changed it back to `... belowSubview: button.titleLabel!)` but it's still unresponsive? have you tried it with just the `containerView` - i'm wondering if that's blocking the user interaction?

Comment: If that is blocking it. Create ypur own button. It should not be difficult to do one. Subclass UIControl which already has all those events which UIButton has and add the effects that you want there.

Comment: the problem was `containerView.userInteractionEnabled = false`, which allows UI events to pass through sub views. many thanks for all your help

Comment: THanks @Alex, I didnt think about that

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with something blocking my button interaction.

But i'm doing the invert process that you do here, i'm adding the button as subview of `UIVisualEffectView `'s `.contentView`

Someone here can help me?