# UIButton loses responsivity(i.e can't press it), maybe because of CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, swift

*Firstly, I think that the problem is on the `UIVisualEffectView`, but now I think that the problem is on the `CGAffineTransform` that I'm using to animate the view on the `openOptionsTooltip()`*

---

First, I found a similar problem on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578490/adding-a-uivisualeffectview-to-button) question (see the comments on the accepted answer), but in my case I'm adding a button as subview of the `UIVisualEffectView`, not adding it as a button subview.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivisualeffectview) says:

> Depending on the desired effect, the effect may affect content layered behind the view or content added to the visual effect view’s contentView.

But I can't find a better explanation on how or why it can affect the content added to the contentView.

- I'm doing all the stuff programmatically, without any xib.
- The visual effect view is a balloon like a tooltip that appears when I touch the titleView.
- I'm creating that view on `viewDidLoad` and holding a
  reference to it on the `viewController`.
- After created, when I click on the titleView I'm adding it as a subview of UIWindow

Here's my code:

**The method to create the view:**

```
    func createOptionsTooltip(withNamesAndActions options: [(name: String , action: Selector)]){

        self.tooltipSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: CGFloat(60*options.count+12))
        var optionItens : [UIView] = []
        for i in 0..<options.count{
            let optionView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: .zero, y: CGFloat(60*i), width: self.tooltipSize.width, height: 60))
            optionView.backgroundColor = .clear

            let separatorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: .zero, y: 59, width: self.tooltipSize.width, height: 1))
            separatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 0.5)
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: .zero, y: .zero, width: self.tooltipSize.width, height: 59))
            button.setTitle(options[i].name, for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(self.view.tintColor, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: options[i].action, for: .touchUpInside)
            button.isEnabled = true
            button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            optionView.addSubview(button)
            optionView.addSubview(separatorView)
            optionView.bringSubviewToFront(button)

            optionItens.append(optionView)
        }


        self.blackOpaqueView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        self.blackOpaqueView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.blackOpaqueView.alpha = 0
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ScheduleNavigationController.closeOptionsTooltip))
//        blackOpaqueView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

        self.vwTooltip = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.midX - self.tooltipSize.width/2, y: self.view.frame.minY+self.navigationBar.frame.size.height+UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height+10), size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)))
        self.vwTooltip.transform = self.vwTooltip.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 0.01)
        self.vwTooltip.isHidden = true

        let vwAim = UIVisualEffectView(frame: CGRect(x: self.tooltipSize.width/2 - 6, y: 0, width: 12, height: 10))
        let vwBalloon = UIVisualEffectView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: vwAim.frame.size.height, width: self.tooltipSize.width, height: CGFloat(60*options.count)))
        vwBalloon.cornerRadius = 8
        vwBalloon.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        vwBalloon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let bezPath = trianglePathWithCenter(rect: vwAim.frame)

        let maskForPath = CAShapeLayer()
        maskForPath.path = bezPath.cgPath
        vwAim.layer.mask = maskForPath


        vwBalloon.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .prominent)
        vwAim.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .prominent)

        for optionView in optionItens{
            vwBalloon.contentView.addSubview(optionView)
            vwBalloon.bringSubviewToFront(optionView)
        }
        self.vwTooltip.addSubview(vwBalloon)
        self.vwTooltip.addSubview(vwAim)
        self.vwTooltip.bringSubviewToFront(vwBalloon)
        vwBalloon.bringSubviewToFront(vwBalloon.contentView)


    }
```

And I'm calling't on the `viewDidLoad` that way:

```
createOptionsTooltip(withNamesAndActions: [("Sair", #selector(ScheduleNavigationController.closeSchedule(_:))), ("Hoje", #selector(ScheduleNavigationController.scrollToToday(_:)))])
```

**And I'm open the tooltip animated this way:**

```
func openOptionsTooltip(){
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate{

        appDelegate.window?.addSubview(blackOpaqueView)
        appDelegate.window?.addSubview(vwTooltip)
        appDelegate.window?.bringSubviewToFront(vwTooltip)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.blackOpaqueView.alpha = 0.5
        }) { _ in
            self.vwTooltip.isHidden = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.vwTooltip.transform = self.vwTooltip.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 100)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**What I have tried:**

- Bring the buttons and all it's superview in hierarch to front using `bringSubviewToFront`. (I have checked, there's no view on the front of the button)
- change the `isUserInteractEnabled` for all button superviews in hierarch.(for both false and true)
- Change the way that I'm adding the target to buttons, without using the method parameter.
- Change the selector method to any other method that work on other targets and switch the method between `@objc` and `@IBOulet`
- **Change the buttons to a view other than the `UIVisualEffectView`**

**PS:** I found that the `UIVisualEffectView` has 3 subviews, but apparently the contentView is the above view, see the log of printing it's subviews:

```
    ▿ 3 elements
  - 0 : <_UIVisualEffectBackdropView: 0x102dcd140; frame = (0 0; 250 120); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <UICABackdropLayer: 0x280d1b480>>
  - 1 : <_UIVisualEffectSubview: 0x102dcd350; frame = (0 0; 250 120); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x280d15c80>>
  - 2 : <_UIVisualEffectContentView: 0x102dcc940; frame = (0 0; 250 120); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x280d1ace0>>
```

I can't figure out what is blocking the button's user interaction

**Here's the result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem:

After calling the `openOptionsTooltip()` the transform inside't are resizing all it's subview, but the `vwTooltp` itself don't change it's frames, but because it `clipToBounds` property are false, all the subviews are showing, but the user can't access the button actions because the view has 1x1 size. Changing the `openOptionsTooltip()` method to that:

```
func openOptionsTooltip(){
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate{

            appDelegate.window?.addSubview(blackOpaqueView)
            appDelegate.window?.addSubview(vwTooltip)
            appDelegate.window?.bringSubviewToFront(vwTooltip)


             UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, animations:{
                self.blackOpaqueView.alpha = 0.5
            }) { _ in
                self.vwTooltip.isHidden = false
                 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, animations:{
                    self.vwTooltip.transform = self.vwTooltip.transform.translatedBy(x: 1, y: 1)
                    self.vwTooltip.transform = self.vwTooltip.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 100)
                 }){ _ in
                    self.vwTooltip.frame = self.tooltipFrame
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And now it's working properly. Thanks for the responses